# Where to call deallocate a child UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITableView inside UIViewController. The UITableView is not deallocated when UIViewController's `viewDidDisappear` is called. The reference is as follows:

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PostsTableView *postsTable;`

I have an observer inside `UITableView` that I must remove when its `dealloc` is called. If I set `postsTable` to `nil` on `viewDidDisppear` when the viewController `didAppear` again, the tableView is not initialized again.

How should I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UITableview pointer will be deallocated when the UIViewcontroller is deallocated.

You can remove your observer when the dealloc function of the UIViewcontroller is called.

Alternatively you can remove the observer on the viewDidDisappear method and set it on the viewDidAppear method...